# What is the rs-485 protocol for controlling old flipdot displays?

Tags: display, protocol, rs485

I have an old Luminator flipdot 16x112 pixel bus destination sign I'd like to hack.  There are numerous resources on the internet for controlling the flipdot display panels with new circuitry, ignoring the existing circuitry, but I would like to get it working with custom messaging in less time than it would take to design, or even build, a custom hardware solution.

The display I have already includes a power supply and control board, and it communicates with the master controller via RS-485.

This particular design is early 90's, with 8051 processors, EEPROMs, and lots of off the shelf logic chips and ULN2xxx series drivers. A middle ground would probably be to remove the 8051, figure out the schematic, and drive the relevant lines with a microcontroller of my own.

Before I give up and go the hard or middle route, does anyone have knowledge of the protocol that is used for these displays?

I do have the master controller and the Luminator control panel, so a path for custom messaging using these elements would be acceptable in the short term.

Comment: Can you make the three units work together? If so, the best route would probably be to put a protocol sniffer of some sort on the RS-485 bus and see what traffic gets sent when, and try to correlate that with what actually appears on the display.

Comment: This [operation manual](http://www.verngibson.com/projects/flip-dot/IDS_Operation_Manual.pdf) has a lot of hints about how the various units work together in the system, although it doesn't go into the details of the RS-485 protocol. It also hints that the firmware for the 8051 is in an external EPROM, which should be straightforward to disassemble.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that manual, and can sniff the bus to try and understand the protocol. It still seems like a pretty lengthy process. That's my next step, though, spending an a hour with the setup and trying to decipher the protocol.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this protocol? I got some Hanover displays recently and it's the same deal, but I don't have anything to drive them with at all to sniff.

Comment: No, I've set it aside due to time limitations.

Comment: Any news on this? I noticed this guy has done it. [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bFaap7DbPU)

Comment: @SenPie No, I have not done anything with my display yet.

Answer (score 1):

So, I realize I'm a bit late to the party here, but maybe someone will still find this useful. I've documented the protocol used by Luminator MAX 3000 and Horizon signs at https://alusch.github.io/flipdot-protocol. I think your sign is a bit older and uses a slightly different protocol, but hopefully it's at least a decent starting point.